# Distribution of distances between points in Gaussian sample

Tags: normal-distribution, distance

Given a sample of $N$ points $\{\mathbf{x}_i\}$ from a bivariate Normal distribution (arbitrary mean and covariance matrix, though I'm mainly interested in the zero-mean case), how does one derive the distribution of the pairwise Euclidian distances between the points? That is, the distribution of {$|\mathbf{x}_i - \mathbf{x}_j|$} for all $i, j \in 1, .., N$ with $i \ne j$?

Comment: According to the Pythagorean formula, this is the the square root of the sum of two independent $\Gamma(1/2)$ distributions with different scales.  It has no simple expression, so what form do you want it in?

Comment: $\mathbf{x_i}-\mathbf{x_j}$ is itselve bivariate normal distributed (with a similar covariance matrix but multiplied by the square of two). This allows you to simplify the question. But still, you get whuber's comment as answer.

Comment: Thanks! @whuber, I don't think this is correct, as $\Gamma(1/2)$ peaks at 0 irrespective of the scale (unless I misunderstood the definition of $\Gamma$)? Simulations show the resulting distribution does not peak at 0, but at a positive value.

Comment: @SextusEmpiricus, do you have a reference for this result?

Comment: @lab a sum of two independent normal bivariate distributed variables is itselve a normal bivariate variable. See for more here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/9879/addition-of-multivariate-gaussians

Comment: @lab *"I don't think this is correct,"* consider the specific case when the scale is 2. Then Γ(1/2,2) would be more specificly a chi squared distribution. While the *individual* distributions peak at 0, this is not true for the *sum* (which is clearly a Γ(2/2,2) chi-squared distribution); the sum will not peak at zero. Could you address the more important part of Whuber's comment and answer the final sentence?

Comment: I get it now. It's not completely clear to me how one derives that the answer is the sum of two $\Gamma$ distributions. Ideally, the final answer should be parameterized in terms of the input mean and (co)variance matrix - perhaps a more tractable version exists in the case of zero mean and no covariance?

Comment: Yes: that reduces to a multiple of a $\chi(2)$ distribution.

Answer (score 1):

- Simplify the problem to a single multivariate Gaussian distribution.

  The difference of two independent bivariate normal distributed variables is itself a bivariate normal distributed variable. The difference is a special case of a linear sum. For that general case see: [Addition of multivariate gaussians](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/9879/addition-of-multivariate-gaussians)
- Simplify the problem to a case without correlation.

  To compute the distribution of the distance $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ we can assume without loss of generality that the correlation is zero. (we can transform non-zero correlation problems into zero correlation problems by performing a rotation which leaves the distance unchanged, but can make the correlation zero).
- The problem is now equivalent to finding the distribution of $\sqrt{aX^2+bY^2}$ where $X,Y \sim N(0,1)$.

  Alternatively, with another transformation, we may look for $aX^2+bY^2$ and the solution for that has been described in a question on the mathematics stackexchange [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2393055/466748). There are currently two answers, one of them gives a closed expression in terms of Bessel fuctions.