# Expected Value of the Difference Between the Powers of Two Randomly Selected Numbers From a Standard Normal Distribution

Tags: normal-distribution, random-variable, expected-value, differences

My question is similar to (and an extension of) [this one](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/587567/distribution-of-distances-between-points-in-gaussian-sample).

I select two values ($i$ and $j$) at random from a standard normal distribution. What is the expected value of $|x_i^n-x_j^n|$ for all integer powers of $n$? The vertical bars represent absolute value symbols, so I know the answer will be a positive number for all values of $n$.

From [this website](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-expected-distance-between-two-independent-draws-from-a-Normal-distribution), I know that, for $n = 1$, the expected value will be $2 / \sqrt\pi$, but I'm not sure about all other values of $n$. I'm hoping to find an equation that relates $n$ with the expected value; I suspect that it will involve an exponential term and a factorial (or gamma-function-like) term like the formula at the bottom of [this website](https://srabbani.com/moments.pdf) has, but I'm not quite able to figure it out myself.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Expressing the integral in polar coordinates shows it's separable.  The radial integral is a Gamma function of $n.$ The angular integral can be broken into eight equal sectors where, on each sector, you need to integrate $\cos^n(\theta)\pm \sin^n(\theta),$ which is elementary.

Comment: You can typeset math here using MathJax: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/321264.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a solution aided interactively with a computer algebra system which does not get all of it by itself, but certainly assists the path to finding the solution.

Let $X$ and $Y$ be independent $\text{N(0,1)}$ drawings, with joint pdf $f(x,y)$:

[image]

The problem is to find:   $\quad E\big[\space \big|{X^n - Y^n} \big| \space \big]   \quad \quad \text{for positive integer} \space n$.

Trying the obvious integrations with a computer algebra system (here  *Mathematica and mathStatica*) just yields an unevaluated integral. So, instead, consider say the first positive 20 integers:

[image]

... and solve $E\big[\space \big|{X^n - Y^n} \big| \space \big]$ for $n$ = 1 to 20:

[image]

This can be seen to contain two sequences:

- one sequence for ODD-valued $n$ of form:

$$\frac{{2^\frac{3-n}{2}}}{\sqrt \pi}\big\{1, \space 5, \space 43, \space 531, \space 8601, \space 172965 ...\big\}$$

where the latter sequence is in the [Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences](https://oeis.org/A090470), and can be generated by:

$$ \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} 2^{\frac{n-1}{2}} n\text{!!} B_{\frac{1}{2}}\left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{n+1}{2}\right)  \quad \text{denoting the incomplete Beta function}$$

- one sequence for EVEN-valued $n$ of form:

$$\frac{4}{\pi} \big \{1, \space 4, \space 22, \space 160, \space 1464, \space 16224 ...\big \}$$

where the latter sequence is also in the [Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences](https://oeis.org/A087547), and can be generated by:

$$n \, _2F_1\left(1,\frac{1-n}{2};\frac{3}{2};-1\right) \Gamma \left(\frac{n}{2}\right)-\sqrt{\pi } 2^{\frac{n}{2}-1} \Gamma \left(\frac{n+1}{2}\right) \quad $$

where 2F1 denotes the Hypergeometric2F1 function.

**In Summary**

- For $n$ odd, the solution is:  $$n\text{!!} \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi }} B_{\frac{1}{2}}\left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{n+1}{2}\right)$$
- For $n$ even, the solution is:

$$ \frac{1}{\pi  \frac{n}{2}!} 2^{1-\frac{n}{2}} \left(2^{n+2} \left(\frac{n}{2}!\right)^2 \, _2F_1\left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{n}{2}+1;\frac{3}{2};-1\right)-\pi  n!\right)$$

**Mathematica code**

- For odd $n$:

  `oddsol = n!! Sqrt[2/Pi] Beta[1/2, 1/2, (n + 1)/2]`

[image]

- For even $n$:

  `evensol = (2^(1 - n/2)*((-Pi)*n! + 2^(2 + n)*(n/2)!^2* Hypergeometric2F1[1/2, 1 + n/2, 3/2, -1]))/(Pi*(n/2)!)`

[image]